# Multiple D3js charts using class selector

Tags: d3.js

I have a table where each row has a percentage value and I'd like to build a pie chart to each row.

Example:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr><th>Activity type</th><th>Progress %</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>Live classes</td><td class="pie-chart">50</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Lessons</td><td class="pie-chart">70</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to replace the percentage values by pie charts showing the progress. I tried to add a class to the cells that have percentage values but I could not put pie charts into them.

I was able to do that using a manual iteration through the cells:

```
var currentPie = d3.select('.pie-chart');

while ( currentPie[0][0] != null ) {
    // ... Code to create the pie chart.

    // Remove the class so the next item will be different.
    currentPie.attr('class', '');

    // Pick up the next pie chart to build.
    currentPie = d3.select('.pie-chart');
}
```

I'd like to know if there is a simpler/better/more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Why could you not put pie charts into them? What have you tried?

Comment: I added a class to the cells that have numeric values `<td class="pie-chart">50</td>` and tried to use D3.js to replace these numeric values by pie charts. I was able to do that iterating through the cells, but not using automated D3.js iteration. I'd like to know if there is a simpler way to do that.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I edited the question. Please see what I did.

Comment: You could select the `td` elements using `d3.selectAll()`, then bind the data for the pie charts to them and generate the charts.

Comment: But the data that I want to bind to each pie chart is inside the `td` elements (50 and 70 in the example above).

Comment: So you'd need to extract the data first.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I will try to build an array with the data and then use `d3.selectAll()` to build the charts. Thanks!